# How to fix IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7?

Tags: python, pandas, index-error

I'm trying to preprocess data, which is contained in an xlsx file (8 lines and 450 columns of face coordinates)

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel(r'C:\Users\wiss\Face Recognition\FaceNet\Data.xlsx')
coords = df.values
```

And this is the code for the pre-processing

```
from numpy import savez_compressed
from numpy import *
import imageio
for iFace in range(450):
    print(iFace)
    im =  imageio.imread(r'C:\Users\wiss\Face Recognition\FaceNet\Caltech\image_%04d.jpg'%(iFace+1))
    coord = coords[:,iFace]

    x = [int(min(coord[0],coord[2])),int(max(coord[4],coord[6]))]
    y = [int(min(coord[1],coord[3])),int(max(coord[5],coord[7]))]
```

When i execute this cell , i get this error

```
0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-5b4d4a09beeb> in <module>
      8 
      9     x = [int(min(coord[0],coord[2])),int(max(coord[4],coord[6]))]
---> 10     y = [int(min(coord[1],coord[3])),int(max(coord[5],coord[7]))]
     11 
     12     dW = -10

IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Does your excel file have 8 lines of values? Or 7 lines of values and the top line is column names?

Comment: If the list has a size of 7, then (zero indexed) the index range goes form 0 to 6, so there is no index 7

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (since never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (removed).

Comment: The excelfile has 8lines of values from 1 to 8 and there is no linge 0 with has names of column is just numbers